# Javascript implementation of ActionScript 3 EventDispatcher

Tags: javascript, events, actionscript, porting, listeners

I'm porting an ActionScript application to JavaScript, and I'm trying to perfect my EventDispatcher implementation.

A recent problem I had is that the callbacks that I had attached weren't being called with the correct `this` value. The way I temporarily fixed it was to add a third parameter to `addEventListener` with the context to be sent back, but this isn't ideal as it doesn't match the same prototype as the actionscript equivilant.

The other thing I tried is a this.callback -style function, but that has even more problems, especially with `removeEventListener`.

Is there a way to follow ActionScript's event style in Javascript?

My current implentaton is attached below: (depends on jQuery / jQueryMX)

```js
var EventDispatcher = jQuery.Class.extend({
  listeners: {},
  init: function() {
    this.listeners = {};
  },
  addEventListener: function(event, listener, context) {
    if (this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
      this.listeners[event].push([listener,context]);
    } else {
      this.listeners[event] = [[listener,context]];
    }
  }, 
  hasEventListener: function() {
    console.error('hasEventListener unimplemented', arguments);
  },
  removeEventListener: function(event, listener) {
    if (this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
      for (i in this.listeners[event]) {
        if (this.listeners[event][i][0] == listener) {
          this.listeners[event].splice(i,1);
          return true;
        }
      }
    } else {
      //console.log('no listener found for',event,listener,this);
      return false;
    }
  },
  dispatchEvent: function(event) {
    if (event.type && this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(event.type)) {    
      event.currentTarget = this;
      //console.log('dispatchEvent',event,this);
      for (i in this.listeners[event.type]) {
        if (typeof this.listeners[event.type][i][0] == 'function') {
          this.listeners[event.type][i][0].call(this.listeners[event.type][i][1],event);
        } 
      }
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: Interesting question but hard to answer because people would need to understand all your code. Maybe try to write a simpler example to describe your problem.

Comment: I am afraid, you have already implemented the way I would have done it. This is the same sort of problems that was had back in the as2 days. I believe back in as2 I did something like `_this`, and even though the functions `this` would refer to what dispatched the event, `_this` would refer to the class where the function is stored. I cannot say this will also work in JS, but it was a bug I exploited in as2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actionscript 3 and Javascript are fundamentally different languages. You might play around with arguments.callee in your addEventListener function and get some sort of approximation of the AS3 EventDispatcher interface, but it is not possible (or desirable) to match it exactly given the inherent differences between the two languages. The way we typically use EventDispatcher in AS3 relies upon the concept of a [Bound Method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/04_OO_Programming_07.html#129654), which does not exist at all in Javascript.

I'd say your current implementation is not only correct, but more powerful and safer than what you've been shooting for. By passing along and storing the context for each event listener, you're constantly reminding yourself that you're in Javascript, not actionscript, and you're avoiding an entire class of pitfalls that goes along with neglecting the difference between Javascript's function scope and AS3's

Comment: I think in retrospect this is probably the best way too, although my implementation is a bit over-the-top when Function.bind is available in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Think back in AS2 to where you had the delegate utility class that might come in handy.